# Running code during static initialization

Tags: c++

In my program I have the following code:

```
struct C {
    static bool Register();

    // other methods
private:
    // instance data
};

bool Register() {
    // perform registration
    return true;
}

// - - - -

static bool const registered = C::Register();
```

This works, but cppcheck is complaining because it spotted that `registered` is never read after being written.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect (calling the function during static initialization) for a function which returns `void` ?

Comment: One workaround would be to read this value and e.g. log an error if it failed.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct C {
    static bool Register();

    // other mnethods
private:
    // instance data
};

void Register() {
    // perform registration
}

class Registrator
{
  public:
  Registrator() {Register();}
};

static Registrator registrator;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `struct C` here? Did you mean `bool C::Register() {...}`?

Comment: Yeah I just coppied from OP

Answer (score 2):

I am not understanding the design of your class... why have a registration class that calls an outer `Register()` function... Why not something like

```
// C can be a singleton
struct C {
    C() { Register(); }

    static bool Register();

    // other mnethods
private:
    // instance data
};

static C registrator;
```

If C is a singletong could would be like:

```
// C can be a singleton
struct C {
    C& instance() { static C inst; return inst; }
    // other mnethods
private:
    C() { Register(); }
    bool Register();
private:
    // instance data
};

static C& registration = C::instance();
```